# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'network') when using chrome.devtools.network API in my chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I'm creating a chrome extension, which captures files which are being attached when writing emails, and I cannot figure the right usage of the chrome.devtools.network API since it gives me this error above. Does anyone know if you can actually capture the raw data, or have a solution or a different approach?

`**manifest.json**`

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "permissions": [
        "activeTab", 
        "tabs", 
        "storage"
    ],
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js"
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
          "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
          "js": ["content.js"]
        }
    ],
    "action": {
        "default_popup": "index.html"
    },
    "devtools_page": "background.js"

}
```

`**background.js**`

```
chrome.devtools.network.onRequestFinished.addListener(
    function(request) {
      console.log(request)
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be used only inside [devtools_page](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/devtools/), which is html:

```html
<script src=devtools.js></script>
```

This script will run automatically when devtools is opened.
The page itself isn't shown anywhere, but you can inspect it via [devtools-on-devtools](/q/12291138), also via `chrome://extensions` -> details for your extension -> `Inspect views` link, which will be shown when devtools is opened on a normal web page, i.e. not `chrome://`.

You can't load the same script also as `service_worker` as these are entirely different contexts. There's also no need for `service_worker` here.